# Сколько будет seмHадцaTь оTняTь двa (oTвет цифpами) What does this say in russian and what is de answer in russian

Tags: phrase

Сколько будет seмHадцaTь оTняTь двa (oTвет цифpами)

What does this say in russian and what is de answer in russian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "How much is seventeen minus two? (the answer in digits [please])."
Since it asks for the answer in digits, the answer is the same as in English, "15". In Russian, "15" is "пятнадцать".
Still, your capitals inside the Russian words and the "s" are unusual.

Comment: It looks like a variant of captcha, random capital letters and 's' are probably to confuse robots.

Comment: I guess this captcha was meant to confuse not robots but non-Russians.